# ECLIPSE: BUILD FAILED

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, ant

I am trying to build a JAVA EE project in Eclipse Oxygen. My system has Apache ANT version 1.10.2 with Eclipse ANT Runtime having 1.10.1.
While building the concerned xml of my project I am getting the following error:

> ```
>  [exec] BUILD FAILED
>  [exec] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Locator.fromJarURI(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:255)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parseUnknownElement(ProjectHelper2.java:130)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parseAntlibDescriptor(ProjectHelper2.java:110)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Antlib.createAntlib(Antlib.java:91)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.loadAntlib(Definer.java:425)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.execute(Definer.java:277)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.checkNamespace(ComponentHelper.java:874)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.getDefinition(ComponentHelper.java:307)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.createComponent(ComponentHelper.java:284)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.createComponent(ComponentHelper.java:263)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.makeObject(UnknownElement.java:429)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.maybeConfigure(UnknownElement.java:163)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:347)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:179)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.configureProject(ProjectHelper.java:93)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:826)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
>  [exec] Total time: 0 seconds
>  [exec] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Locator.fromJarURI(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:255)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parseUnknownElement(ProjectHelper2.java:130)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parseAntlibDescriptor(ProjectHelper2.java:110)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Antlib.createAntlib(Antlib.java:91)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.loadAntlib(Definer.java:425)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.execute(Definer.java:277)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.checkNamespace(ComponentHelper.java:874)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.getDefinition(ComponentHelper.java:307)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.createComponent(ComponentHelper.java:284)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.createComponent(ComponentHelper.java:263)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.makeObject(UnknownElement.java:429)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.maybeConfigure(UnknownElement.java:163)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:347)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:179)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.configureProject(ProjectHelper.java:93)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:826)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
>  [exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
>  [exec] org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Locator.fromJarURI(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
> ```

```
BUILD FAILED
```

Unable to figure out whether it is due to conflict in version or some other ant error.

Comment: The `NoSuchMethodError` sure suggests a version conflict.

Comment: See if this resolves your problem: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=180834

Comment: This method exists since Ant 1.7.1, so this shouldn't be a version conflict between 1.10.1 and 1.10.2. https://ant.apache.org/manual/api/org/apache/tools/ant/launch/Locator.html#fromJarURI-java.lang.String-

Comment: Seems like, version conflict is not there. As the project build is compatible with ant 1.10.2. Still scratching my head over this issue.